Named + External Credentials issue: Getting 502 error when access token for external system has expired
I'm new to the named credentials + external credentials combo. My task is to integrate with an external system using these features using client credentials flow and OAuth2.0.
I was able to get it working - until my token expired. At which point, I'm getting a 502 error, instead of 401 or 403:
21:38:37:401 NAMED_CREDENTIAL_RESPONSE NamedCallout[Named Credential Id=0XA7f000000CcAh, Named Credential Name=<External Credential>, Status Code=502, Content-Type=application/json; charset=utf-8, Response Size bytes=94, Overall Callout Time ms=356, Connect Time ms=1

This is the only thing I can get from the logs:
21:38:37:398 NAMED_CREDENTIAL_REQUEST NamedCallout[Named Credential Id=0XA7f000000CcAh, Named Credential Name=ZuoraNEWS, Endpoint=<<<<END POINT REDACTED>>>>, Method=GET, External Credential Type=EXTERNAL, HTTP Header Authorization=Method: Bearer - Credential: 11e50703519c45c4424f09611de36454b83b0f7d7697ef0d9438a12209539b8c, Content-Type=application/json; charset=utf-8, Request Size bytes=-1, Retry on 401=True]

And this is the exact message I'm getting:
21:38:37:000 NAMED_CREDENTIAL_RESPONSE_DETAIL   "message":"Invalid content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8 received from upstream server"
Based on this error message, I think the actual request created by Salesforce is malformed.
EDIT [Adding postman screenshots]:
I am not able to reproduce the 502 error in Postman:

If I enter incorrect credentials when getting oauth token, I get 401:

If I perform a callout to Zuora using an incorrect / expired token, I get 401:

If I don't add an Authorization header, I get error 400:

I guess my questions are:

Is there a way I can inspect the actual headers and body that Salesforce sent out?
Is there a way via Apex to manually refresh the access token generated by the External Credential?

UPDATE:
It was recommended to get new access tokens via apex code.
Another question though, if I setup the EC as Client Credentials via Client Secret Flow, as can be seen here, how do I access the merge fields for it?

I can only access it when I setup the EC as Custom, and I add custom parameters.

Client credentials flow doesn't issue a refresh token.  Please edit your question and show the flow that works in Postman.

@identigral done, edited the question. thanks

You can point to a proxy of your choice to inspect headers. In this oAuth flow, you need a new access token when the current one expires, perhaps this is what you mean by "refresh". Sequence: acquire a new access token by posting to /oauth/token -> call your API, rinse and repeat. A good next step would be to 1) make sure your external+named cred is configured correctly 2) invoke your API via Apex with this named/external cred

I used Postman Echo to inspect headers, doesn't look like anything's wrong. I did configure my NC+EC according to the answer you have on that link, and it's working as long as the access token doesn't expire. Is my assumption correct, that if I can configure the endpoint to return a 401, I don't need to manually get a new access token, and that SF will take care of it? @identigral

The 401 et al is for oAuth refresh flow. Since client credentials flow doesn't have the oAuth refresh sequence, there's nothing to refresh the way oAuth spec wants it. The way you want it can be done by your code, Named/Ext cred won't do it.

Thanks @integral so I can only use those 401 if the external service supports OAuth refresh, right?
I did end up doing a manual apex code for it. It would be great if there's a way I can store the new access tokens on the NC or EC.
I edited my question above, do you know how to access the client id + secret in apex via merge fields when using Client Credentials + Secret Flow?
